# SQLAlchemy subquery with AWS Athena

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-athena

I would like to use SQLAlchemy to generate a SQL request instead of achieving string concatenation to request AWS Athena.
What I need is to get all the usernames with a specific `name` from one period of time which are not present in another period of time with another `name`.

The query I want to generate from SQLAlchemy is the following:

```sql
WITH sub_query_1 AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT username
    FROM analytics_events
    WHERE category = 'username'
            AND user_category='xxx'
            AND timestamp >= yyy 
            AND timestamp <= zzz
            AND name = 'aaa'), sub_query_2 AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT username
    FROM analytics_events
    WHERE category = 'username'
            AND user_category='xxx'
            AND timestamp >= yyy
            AND timestamp <= zzz
            AND name = 'bbb'
SELECT sub_query_1.username
FROM sub_query_1
LEFT JOIN sub_query_2
    ON sub_query_1.username = sub_query_2.username
WHERE sub_query_2.username is null
```

I tried to achieve something like that:

```py
name_aaa = (
    Query(column('table.username'))
    .filter(
        and_(
            column('category') == "username",
            column('name') == "aaa",
            column('user_category') == user_category,
            column('timestamp') >= starting_date,
            column('.timestamp') <= ending_aaa_date,
        )
    )
    .subquery()
)
name_bbb = (
    Query(column('table.username'))
    .filter(
        and_(
            column('category') == "username",
            column('name') == "bbb",
            column('user_category') == user_category,
            column('timestamp') >= starting_date,
            column('timestamp') <= now,
        )
    )
    .subquery()
)
query = name_aaa.join(
    name_bbb, and_(name_bbb.c.username == name_aaa.c.username), isouter=True
)
```

But I get the following error:

```sh
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 1203, in __getattr__
    util.raise_(AttributeError(key), replace_context=err)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
AttributeError: email
```

I need to generate SQL from SQLAlchemy (to be executed by boto3 on AWS Athena) so I didn't use an SQLAlchemy session. I have the feeling it makes me using the Query object in the wrong way but I can't figure out what's wrong.